# How to derive or logically explain the formula for curl?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Most books state that the formula for curl of a vector field is given by $\nabla \times \vec{V}$ where $\vec{V}$ is a differentiable vector field. Also, they state that: "The curl of a vector field measures the tendency for the vector field to swirl around".

But, none of them state the derivation of the formula. In other words : "How can we derive the formula for the quantity which measures the tendency for the vector field to swirl around" ?

Comment: @edm I already stated it in the first line.

Comment: Maybe you meant to type curl instead of divergence?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388573/making-the-rigorous-link-between-the-conceptual-interpretation-of-curl-and-the-f/2388632#2388632 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286809/geometric-intuition-behind-gradient-divergence-and-curl?rq=1

Comment: It is NOT a formula. It is more like a definition of curl, unless the book states some other definition of curl.

Comment: @edm That definition obviously didn't come out of thin air. There must be some logic which led to that definition.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to this question is easily Google-able. See, for example, [these notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-90-curl-in-3d/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v4.3.pdf) from MIT OCW on the physical interpretation of the two-dimensional curl.

To briefly summarize: the *circulation* of a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ around a closed loop $c$ is measured by the line integral $\oint_c\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$. If this quantity is nonzero, the field has a tendency to swirl around the loop. The idea of the curl is to measure this effect *microscopically*, as a density, rather than *macroscopically*, as a line integral. In other words, we want the curl to be *the thing we integrate in order to determine the macroscopic circulation*.

So imagine a three-dimensional field $\mathbf{F}$ and a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider a disk $D$ of radius $r$ in some plane that contains $p$. The tendency of the field to swirl around the boundary of the disk $\partial D$ is $\oint_{\partial D}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$. By Green's theorem in the plane containing the disk, this is $\iint_D(\text{curl}\,\mathbf{F})\cdot\mathbf{\hat{n}}\,dA$, where $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is a normal vector to the disk. In other words, the component of the curl in the direction $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the "circulation density" per unit area:

$$(\text{curl}\,\mathbf{F})\cdot\mathbf{\hat{n}}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\iint_D(\text{curl}\,\mathbf{F})\cdot\mathbf{\hat{n}}\,dA = \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\oint_{\partial D}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$$

The quantity $\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\oint_{\partial D}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$ has units (units of circulation) / (units of area). It tells us the average *macroscopic* circulation per unit area for the macroscopic disk $D$. To get a *microscopic* quantity, we just take the limit of this density as we shrink the disk to a point (which here amounts to shrinking the radius $r$ to zero).

Comment: PS: the idea of the derivative as a density should be familiar from single-variable calculus. Think of the ordinary single-variable derivative $f'$ as the "change density" (per unit length) of the function $f$. The *macroscopic* change in the quantity $f$ over some interval $(a, a+h)$ is $f(a+h)-f(a)$. So the *average macroscopic* change density per unit length is $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$. We get the *microscopic* change density $f'(a)$ by taking the limit as we shrink the interval to a point, i.e. as $h\to0$. (For fancier language, replace the word "change" with the word "flux.")

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer for the 2-dimensional curl only.  Hopefully one can turn it into a general argument for 3 dimensions.

Consider a perfect rotation of the plane around the origin, in which, at time $t$,  a point $(x,y)$ is sent to
$$
  R_t(x,y) =
  \left[\matrix {\cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t) \cr \sin(\omega t) & \hfill\cos(\omega t)}\right]
  \left[\matrix {x \cr y }\right] =
  \left[\matrix {x\cos(\omega t)  -y \sin(\omega t) \cr x\sin(\omega t) + y\cos(\omega t)}\right].
  $$

Observe that each point completes a full turn, namely $2\pi $ radians, as $t$ goes from zero to $2\pi /\omega $, so the angular velocity is
$$
  \frac{\Delta \theta }{\Delta t} = \frac{2\pi }{2\pi /\omega } = \omega .
  $$

The linear velocity vector at time zero of each point $(x, y)$ is given by
$$
  \left.\frac d{dt}\right|_{\, t=0}  R_t(x,y) =
  \left[\matrix {-\omega x\sin(\omega t)  -\omega y \cos(\omega t) \cr
  \hfill \omega x\cos(\omega t) - \omega y\sin(\omega t)}\right]_{\, t=0} =
  \left[\matrix {-\omega y \cr \hfill \omega x}\right],
  $$
so the velocity vector field may be represented by
$$
  F(x,y) = (-\omega y,\omega x) = \omega (-y,x).
  $$

Given any point $(x, y)$ in the plane, let $C$ be  the circle about the origin passing thru $(x,y)$, and observe that
the unit vector $\vec t\ $ tangent to $C$ at $(x,y)$ is given by

[image]

If we project   $F(x,y)$ onto this vector (notice that these vectors are parallel, although in the more general situation
we are about to consider  they might not be), we get the component of $F(x,y)$ that is causing a rotation around the origin, which is then given by
$$
  \langle F(x,y),\vec t\ \rangle  =
  \left\langle (-\omega y,\omega x), \frac{(-y, x)}{\|(x, y)\|} \right\rangle   =
  \frac{\omega (y^2+x^2)}{\|(x, y)\|} =
  \omega \|(x, y)\|.
  $$
Consequently we may estimate the value of $\omega $ in terms of the vector field at any point $(x,y)$  by the simple formula
$$
  \omega  = \frac{\langle F(x,y),\vec t\ \rangle }{\|(x, y)\|}.
  \tag 1
  $$

If,  instead of the origin, we consider a rotation about another point $(x_0, y_0)$, so that
$$
  R_t(x,y) =
  \left[\matrix {x_0 \cr y_0 }\right] +
  \left[\matrix {\cos(\omega t) & -\sin(\omega t) \cr \sin(\omega t) & \hfill\cos(\omega t)}\right]
  \left[\matrix {x-x_0 \cr y-y_0 }\right] =
  \left[\matrix {x_0 +  (x-x_0)\cos(\omega t)  -(y-y_0) \sin(\omega t) \cr y_0 +(x-x_0)\sin(\omega t) + (y-y_0)\cos(\omega t)}\right],
  $$
the corresponding velocity vector field would be given by
$$
  F(x,y) = \omega (-y+y_0,x-x_0),
  $$
while   estimate (1) would be written as
$$
  \omega  = \frac{\langle F(x,y),\vec t\ \rangle }{\|(x-x_0, y-y_0)\|},
  \tag 2
  $$
where $\vec t$ is now given by
$$
  \vec t = \frac{(-y+y_0, x-x_0)}{\|(x-x_0, y-y_0)\|}.
  $$

Now suppose we are presented with an arbitrary vector field on the plane, say
$$
  F(x,y) =\big (P(x,y),Q(x,y)\big ),
  $$
and we want to estimate how much it rotates about a point $(x_0, y_0)$.

Notice that (2) would no longer  be of much use since the field might perhaps be constant, meaning that  all points are moving along
the same direction, without any rotation taking place, and still the RHS of (2) could yield a meaningless big value of $\omega $.

If you hold a child by the hand when strolling,   you might not know whether they are walking straight or dancing around.  But if the parents each hold one hand, it is much easier to tell!

To account for this,  let us choose many points,  rather than just one, and average the outcomes of (2) for these
points.  A reasonable choice would be four points, to the right, to the left, above and below the point  $(x_0,y_0)$
under consideration.

Fixing  a parameter $h>0$, let us then consider the following four points
$$
  \matrix{
  (x_1, y_1) &=& (x_0+h, y_0) & \quad \text{(right)} \cr
  (x_2, y_2) &=& (x_0-h, y_0) & \quad \text{(left)}  \cr
  (x_3, y_3) &=& (x_0, y_0+h) & \quad \text{(above)} \cr
  (x_4, y_4) &=& (x_0, y_0-h) & \quad \text{(below)}
}
  $$

[image]

Regarding   $(x_1, y_1)$, for example, we would have
$$
  \vec t = (0, 1),
  $$
so
$$
  \omega _1 =
  \frac{\langle F(x_0+h,y_0),(0, 1)\rangle }{\|(h, 0)\|} =
  \frac{Q(x_0+h,y_0)}h.
  $$
Averaging the four  angular velocity  estimates $\omega _1$, $\omega _2$, $\omega _3$, and $\omega _4$,  we get
$$
  \frac {\omega _1+ \omega _2 +\omega _3 + \omega _4}4 =
  \frac { Q(x_0+h,y_0) - Q(x_0-h,y_0) - P(x_0,y_0+h) - P(x_0,y_0-h)}{4h}.
  $$
In order to compute  the infinitesimal  angular velocity at $(x_0,y_0)$ we take the limit as $h\to 0$, which we may
compute using L'Hopital rule, leading up to
$$
  \lim_{h\to 0_+}  \frac {\omega _1+ \omega _2 +\omega _3 + \omega _4}4 =
  \frac 1 4 \left(\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) + \frac {\partial Q}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)
  - \frac {\partial P}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) - \frac {\partial P}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right) = $$$$ =
  \frac 1 2 \left(\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) - \frac {\partial P}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\right) =
  \frac 1 2 \text{ curl }F(x_0,y_0).
  $$

---

Although I was brought up as a mathematician, I was always much irritated when professors introduced new
concepts named after physically significant phenomenon without explaining in depht where   the motivation for the
name came from.  Some of my first
disapointments occured precisely when I was first confronted with the notions of gradient, divergent and curl.

Searching for an explanation does not always bring about any light and this in fact makes me suspect that lots of grown ups
have been force fed these concepts to the point that they eventually seem natural,  after which one no longer feels the  need for any further explanations.

Take the [MIT course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-90-curl-in-3d/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v4.3.pdf) mentioned in @symplectomorphic's answer,  for example.
There, Green's Theorem is used to explain that the 2-dimensional curl is related to the angular velocity of a small
paddle wheel.  Could Green's Theorem historically have come before the notion of curl?
To me this makes no sense as it  might give  students the impression that Green first obtained his formula out of the blue and then, as an
afterthought, realized that his Theorem could be used to deduce that the  curl represents the rotation of a vector field.